# Raspberry Pi 3 using Hostapd and dnsmasq how to set default web page on connect

Tags: raspberry-pi, dnsmasq, hostapd

I have set up hostapd and dnsmasq to run on my Raspbian RPi3. This works great.

I also have apache2 running on this RPi with a web site.

How do I now make it so that everyone who connects to my RPi AP gets redirected to the default page of the web site running on the RPi?

Comment: I've never actually done this, so I'm not confident enough to make this an answer, but I think what you're looking for is a "captive portal", such as nocat or wifidog.

Comment: That should work for my needs. Please repost as an answer so I can mark it so...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways:

The first is using IPTABLES rule to redirect all traffic to your server on port 80

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 0/0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 111.222.333.444:80
```

You will need to *install iptables-persistent* to keep this rule after reboot/shutdown.

The second one is using an dnsmasq option on */etc/dnsmasq.conf*:

> **From dnsmasq man**: Add domains which you want to force to an IP address here.  The
>   example below send any host in doubleclick.net to a local  webserver.
>
> address=/doubleclick.net/127.0.0.1

You can also use a wildcard to redirect all traffic from all sources/domains to your webserver.

```
address=/#/127.0.0.1
```